# Base Base Constructor C# initialization

Tags: c#, inheritance

A simplified scenario. Three clases, GrandParent, Parent and Child. What I want to do is to make use of the GrandParent and Parent constructor to initalize a Child instance.

```
class GrandParent ()
{
    public int A {get; protected set;}
    public int B {get; protected set;}

    public GrandParent (int a, int b);
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

class Parent : GrandParent ()
{
    public Parent () {}
}
```

Child Class, were the problem occurs.

```
class Child : Parent ()
{
    public int C {get; protected set}

    public Child (int c) // here I want it to also call the GrandParent (int a, int b)
                         // before calling Child (int c)
    {
        C = c;
    }
}

Child = new Child (1,2,3);
```

What I want is that the variables a,b and c to get 1,2 respectively 3 as values. I know I can solve it by simply adding `A = a` and `B = b` to the `Child` constructor.

Is this possible? If so how?

I begun looking at base () however it looked like it was only able to access the `Parent` class and not the `GrandParent`.

Thanks in advance.

PS. If it has been asked before, I apologize in advance, I did not find anything.

Quick edit: I am trying to make the solution as easy as possible to work with, to develop further.

Comment: For this to even compile, wouldn't `Parent` need a constructor that takes two arguments?

Comment: This does not currently compile, what I am using right now is `A=a` and `B=b` as well as taking in its arguments into Child. My question regards if it is possible without?

Comment: There's also a syntax error, as there should be no parentheses `()` after the name of the class.

Comment: The moral of the story is, we should avoid using `Parent`, `Grandparent` and `Child` as example names when explaining inheritance. A *child* is not a type of *parent*, a *parent* is not a type of *grandparent*. The names don't adequately explain the hypernym/homonym relationship, and so it isn't as immediately obvious that "thing that can be created without an A or B being set" cannot be a type of "thing that can only be created with an A or B being set".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# good practise assumes that you call base class constructor in every child. That said, you'll call base(a,b) from parent and base(a,b) from child, which will invoke grandparent ctor. That grants you incapsulation. Here is you code snippet rewriten:

```
class GrandParent ()
{
    public int A {get; protected set;}
    public int B {get; protected set;}

    public GrandParent (int a, int b);
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

class Parent : GrandParent ()
{
    public Parent (int a, int b):base(a,b) {}
}
Child Class, were the problem occurs.

class Child : Parent ()
{
    public int C {get; protected set}

    public Child (int a, int b, int c):base(a,b)
    {
        C = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only invoke the constructors to the direct superclass. The direct superclass needs to expose the options that you need. It can safely do this with a `protected` constructor.

Comment: +1 Was verifying this on MSDN when you posted. `base` always goes to the direct parent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variables through each constructor to its base constructor:

```
class Child : Parent ()
{
    public int C {get; protected set}

    public Child (int a, int b, int c) : base(a,b)
                         // before calling Child (int c)
    {
        C = c;
    }
}

Child = new Child (1,2,3);

class GrandParent ()
{
    public int A {get; protected set;}
    public int B {get; protected set;}

    public GrandParent (int a, int b);
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

class Parent : GrandParent ()
{
    public Parent (int a, int b) : base(a,b) {}
}
```

Comment: I suspected as much, making it cleaner to some extent. Not as clean as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 1):

*parent* and *child* is an analogy of limited applicability, because a derived class is not a "child" of the base as a person's or animal's child is a child of them, or even as a subdirectory is of a directory or dependent node in a tree (GUI or data-structure).

The relationship is actually that of hypernym to hyponym. Sadly, *hypernym* isn't as well-known a word as *parent*, so people often use the less-accurate *parent* in explaining inheritance rather than *hypernym*.

Now, let's consider the first class declaration:

```
class GrandParent
{
    public int A {get; protected set;}
    public int B {get; protected set;}

    public GrandParent (int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

This is exactly as in the question, except the erroneous `()` on the first line and `;` on the sixth have been removed.

It has a single constructor, that takes two integers.

This means either:

1. It makes no logical sense for a `GrandParent` to ever be created, without two integers being passed.
2. There's a bug in how this was defined.
3. Okay, maybe not a bug, but certainly a tad lazy.

When we come to the declaration of `Parent`:

```
class Parent : GrandParent
{
    public Parent () {}
}
```

Here I've fixed the syntax errors, but nothing else.

Since there is no explicit use of `base` in the constructor there is an implied call to a parameterless `base()`. That is, the above is exactly the same as:

```
class Parent : GrandParent
{
    public Parent()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Any call to `new Parent()` will through the `base()` call `new GrandParent()`. Since there is no parameterless constructor on `GrandParent()` this can't compile.

And here the language rules are helping us:

1. We said that it makes no sense for a `GrandParent` to be created without two integers being used.
2. We said that a `Parent` is a type of `GrandParent`.
3. We said that a `Parent` is only ever created without those two integers being set.

We said three things are true that cannot all be true. The language rules are correct to point out our mistake.

To fix this we need to either:

1. Allow a `GrandParent` to be created without those two integers being used in its construction.
2. Force `Parent`s to always have two integers being used in their construction, which are then in turn used in turn with the base constructor.
3. Have the parameterless constructor on `Parent` call `base(a, b)` with some set values.
4. Do a mixture of the above. E.g. we could have both set values called if the parameterless constructor was called, and also another constructor that passes arguments to the base constructor.

The 3rd above would look something like:

```
class Parent : GrandParent
{
    public Parent()
        : base(42, -343213)
    {
    }
}
```

Or whatever, as long as those numbers come from somewhere (obviously in real code they would relate to something more sensible than my random typing).

Now we have a `Parent` that actually makes logical sense, and the rest can follow.

Comment: Thank you. I think I now understand it. Sorry for the small errors, I rewrote the code to minimize it.